# CosmosDB Graph DB Size

Tags: graph-databases, azure-cosmosdb

I have a graph collection that is just a single 10GB collection and have inserted about 37000 vertices and edges(combined).  I started to get errors about reaching the storage quota for it but I should be nowhere near the storage quota.  The storage metrics page says I am at 10GiB with 36.97K documents. I queried samples of these vertices and edges and uploaded the json to the Capacity Planner (https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner) and according to that my total data storage for what is there should be around 30.75MB. I uploaded two sample files (a vertex sample and an edge sample and input the exact qty of each of them to obtain that 30.75MB number.

For sample document 1 11.21 KB x 18560 = 18.71 MB

For sample document 2 20.85 KB x 18405 = 12.04 MB

Why and how would this run the collection up to the max size? What is going on with this?

Comment: Are you using the default index settings or have you modified them in any way?

Comment: Just the default (whatever is set when you create a graph collection via portal UI). Even then, I would find it hard to believe that the index would take up 99+ % of the space. The portal doesn't give you info on index size vs data size so no way to see that there.  Wouldn't the capacity planner take into account at least the default index settings in its calculations.

Comment: It does give you the breakdown of data vs index. Just click on Metrics under the Monitoring section and then click on the Storage Tab and you can see the breakdown

Comment: I see what you are talking about. Didn't even notice because it didn't even register on the graph. It appears to be registering near zero for index and 10GB for data.  Also, I just ran through the change feed and the numbers above are correct.  36.965 total items. I serialized them as json just for my own sanity and the byte count came out to a little over 20 MB.  If I expand the storage graph, it gives more details and shows data at 9.9GB and index at 14.82MB.  I know my data is not 9.9GB.

Comment: One more thing.  The overview area that lists the collections shows the storage to be 49.04MB

Comment: There is definitely something hosed up.  I deleted the collection and it still shows me using 10GB even though I have no collections in the account.

Comment: It sounds very strange, I suggest you could create a support ticket to connect to azure support team to help you solve this issue.

Comment: To add this when I created a second collection it still showed there was and extra 10 GB in use.  After a while it finally went away after having deleted it.  It is pretty concerning since that could happen to a production data set and cause it to fail and reject requests.